# My apache server is running but when I go to webpage it says network connection timed out

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, apache2

I am using LAMP server on a raspberry pi and my apache server has stopped displaying the website (page).

I have already tried restarting the server and my whole Pi
it is a rasperry pi 3 and the apache version is 2.0 the other components of the lamp server are working

I entered this command in terminal

`sudo apache2`

and it gave me this:

```
[Sun Dec 23 10:38:11.948939 2018] [core:warn] [pid 2061] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must launch it with its service, not directly with its executable.

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```